# How can -ㄹ래 be used to express my intentions, and also to ask someone else about their intentions?

Tags: grammar

I came across the sentence below in Naver which serves as a definition to the '-ㄹ래' 어미.

> 해할 자리에 쓰여, 장차 어떤 일을 하려고 하는 스스로의 의사를 나타내거나 상대편의 의사를 묻는 데 쓰이는 종결 어미.

I broke the definition into 4 simple sentences to understand it better.

> 1. '-ㄹ래'는 종결 어미이다.
> 2. '-ㄹ래'를 해할 자리에 쓰이다.
> 3. 장차 어떤 일을 하려고 하는 스스로의 의사를 나타내는 데 '-ㄹ래'를 쓴다.
> 4. 상대편의 의사를 묻는 데 '-ㄹ래'를 쓴다.

However, I still need some examples in which '-ㄹ래' is used as explained in (3) and (4) to tell the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a South Korean.

"해할 자리에 쓰여, 장차 어떤 일을 하려고 하는 스스로의 의사를 나타내거나 상대편의 의사를 묻는 데 쓰이는 종결 어미."

This sentence is quite difficult to understand even for me. We normally don't study Korean like this.

Anyways, I want to give you some examples.
(3) 나 밥 먹을래 : I wanna/will eat a meal. 
(4) 너 밥 먹을래? : Do you want to have a meal?

(3) 나 집에 갈래 : I wanna/will go home.
 - 
(4) 우리 집에 갈래? : Do you want to visit my house? (Actually 우리=나 here, we call my house 우리 집, not 나 집)

(3) 나 죽을래 : I will kill myself (we never say like this. but for practicing.)

(4) 너 죽을래? : Do you wanna die? (we use it a lot. hmm... difficult to explain. Googling it. Sorry.)

So far, (3) and (4) is almost the same. 
For (3), the agent always is me. In (4), the agent is the other person (not me). 

When you speak, you have to finish the end of the sentence with high tone(high pitch) in case (4). On the other hand, maintain tone when you speak (3) case.

My English is not so good. If there are parts you don't understand, reply again please. Or correct my sentence, please.

Comment: @HusainAbdali Welcome. You might wanna forget about the grammar stuff. '해할자리', '종결어미' these words are used by linguists. Common people don't care about these. It could be an obstacle for learning. Haha. In my opinion.....

Comment: @TINGCHOE Unless you are a Linguistics Enthusiast, dear

Comment: I thought the first person use was more like "wanna" ("want to", spoken informally) expressing a mild intention.  "Will" seems a bit strong of a translation, don't you think?

Comment: By saying "get to" (in the 2nd #3) are you implying enthusiasm, like a child would say "I get to go home early" or "I get to eat ice cream" kind of thing?   That seems odd, but then I'm not Korean...is this your intention here?

Comment: @B.Alvn I didn't know that there are some differences in get to, have to, wanna and want to. Sorry. I just focused on the meaning. As a non-native English speaker, I don't know about it. ~ㄹ래 is normally mild intention but I think you can use this as strong intention.

Comment: @TINGCHOE  there are differences: 'get to' normally means you are happy or enthusiast about it (I get to eat ice cream after school); 'have to' means you must, even if you don't want to (I have to go to work); 'wanna' is a mild wish or intention (I wanna see that movie.  I wanna go to Paris someday'); "want to" is the same as 'wanna' except more proper language.  Would you agree that ~기로 하다 or 려고 하다 are used for  stronger intentions than ㄹ래 ?

Comment: I edited accepting yours. It can be both according to situations.

Comment: @TINGCHOE Very different.  'wanna' is as just said.  Will, used in the first person, definitely expresses either intent (I will do my homework tonight) or a statement about the future you are sure about (These geese will fly south this winter)

Comment: @B.Alvn Well.... Both ~려고 하다 and ㄹ래 are one's intention. I think they are the same. ~기로 하다 is an promise, appointment, plan or one's intention. It's stronger than those because you should keep the promise. As you know, it can varies depending on the situation.

Comment: @HusainAbdali  As a linguistics enthusiast, you may wish to know that in modern English, you would use the lower case 'l' and 'e' there.

Comment: @B.Alvn Is it important? I mean, capital vs. lower case.

Comment: @TINGCHOE It is very old-fashioned to use capital letters like that, but you see it in old classic literature still.  Not that important, but not remotely considered modern.  These days, only proper nouns (names of people, institutions, places, etc), the pronoun 'I', the first letter of a sentence, titles, and most abbreviations are normally capitalized.  Also, in some scientific, medical, and other fields certain terms are sometimes capitalized.  I'm sure there are more examples I'm not thinking of right now.

Comment: @B.Alvn Okay. Ty for English lecture, man~

Comment: @TINGCHOE thanks for your information as well.  최팅?  That is an unusual Korean name...

Comment: @B.Alvn Obviously, it's not my real name. I've never heard about Korean names which has letter '팅'.

Comment: I have 3 friends in Korea with 최 and they usually spell it "Choe" (or Choi) so I just assued that was probably your name...sorry, man~

Comment: 최 is my family name. South Koreans sometimes make nickname changing only their given name. Like this, 판테온 -->최테온. 꼴초-->최꼴초.

Comment: @TINGCHOE '팅' is not a letter!

Comment: Learn something new everyday! :)